# SQL - enhance schema to count unread messages

Tags: sql, schema, messaging

I have a simple message schema where a "thread" ties 2 or more users to a stream of messages. Each message belongs to a single thread. It works just like SMS messages, or Facebook messages.

I only need to count how many threads have new messages for a given user. When a user opens a thread, I need to update the db (for that user only), indicating that they have looked at the thread. Given these 2 tables, how should I enhance my schema to store this "updated thread" data for each user in each thread?

**MessageThreads:**
threadID
lastUpdated

**MessageThreadUsers:**
threadFK
userFK

I'm thinking along the lines of adding this table (but is there a better way???)

**UserThreads**
userFK
threadFK
lastChecked

Comment: Since `UserThreads` has the same keys as `MessageThreadUsers`, why not just add your new `lastChecked` column to the `MessageThreadUsers` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add a lastChecked column to your MessageThreadUsers table. Then you can compare that value to the lastUpdated field in MessageThreads to determine whether the user has new messages. Or something like below should give you the total number of new messages.

```
SELECT COUNT(mtu.*) FROM MessageThreadUsers mtu JOIN MessageThreads mt ON mt.threadID = mtu.threadFK WHERE mtu.lastChecked < mt.lastUpdated GROUP BY mtu.userFK
```

Comment: Nice... I'll try it out. Seems way too logical!!! :) I don't know why I thought I needed another table!

Answer (score 0):

What about some kind of `unread` boolean value in `MessageThreads`? When a thread is updated, `unread` is set to `true`. When a user checks a thread, set it to `false`.

Just a thought.

Comment: Multiple users can be part of the same thread, so the unread flag would need to apply to a user/thread combination, not just a thread.